# Service Worker controllerChange only for skipWaiting()

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm using the well known event listener 'controllerchange' to detect activation of a new service worker since I'm using both clients.claim() and skipWaiting().

'controllerchange' event is fired on the first load as expected, but I would like to distinguish only the 'skipWaiting()' activation.

I even tried using 'updatefound' event, but it is fired on first load as well..

Answer (score 1):

As per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/oncontrollerchange):

> The `oncontrollerchange` property of the ServiceWorkerContainer
> interface is an event handler fired whenever a `controllerchange` event
> occurs — when the document's associated `ServiceWorkerRegistration`
> acquires a new `active` worker.

If you want to detect when there's a `controllerchange` *and* it's due to a `waiting` service worker becoming `active`, I would recommend storing the initial `controller` service worker in a variable, if there is one, and then inside of the `controllerchange` event listener, determine whether there was a `controller` service worker initially. That will tell you whether the new service worker in control of the page was the result of an update or not.

Please note that there's a bit of a race condition here, as the code that checks for an initial `controller` might not execute until after the updated service worker takes control, assuming you're calling `skipWaiting()` and `clients.claim()` in your updated service worker. That may or may not matter to you—I don't know if you need to detect this with 100% accuracy.

```
const originalSW = navigator.serviceWorker.controller;
navigator.serviecWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
  if (originalSW) {
    // This is due to an update.
  } else {
    // This is due to a SW taking control for the first time.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that will possibly work in most of the cases like you've already said,
but I would like to Know if there is an option to actually distinguish the first install/activation.
I tried listening to 'stateChange' and read the event that 'controllerChange' returned and found nothing realted to skipWaiting()

Comment: The `else` clause in my example is what would execute if this is first install/activation.